# Is there any injective mapping from smooth functions on closed interval to smooth functions on circle? Motivated by signal processing

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, smooth-manifolds, signal-analysis

One advantage of Discrete Cosine Transform (DCT) over Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT) is that DCT maps any "continuous" signal defined on interval to a continuous one defined on circle.

I will omit this signal processing stuff and just describe what it means in our every-day mathematical language.

Let say we have a continuous function $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$, and we wish to decompose it into countable series of whole-valued frequencies. Thus, we would have to wrap $f$ around the circle and in general it would result in discontinuity (see image below) since in general $f(0)\neq f(1).$

The trick with Cosine Transform is to reflect $f$ across $y$-axis resulting in function defined on $[-1,1]$. This function has equal values at boundaries so it could be wrapped around circle continuously (see image below).

[image]

I wonder if the trick from Cosine Transform can be pushed further to preserve smoothness. More precisely, is there any injective operation $\Phi$ such that it maps any smooth function $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ to a smooth function $\Phi(f):S^1\to\mathbb{R}$? If so, is there any "simple" such $\Phi$ like in the Cosine Transform?

Comment: Just checking: Smooth means infinitely differentiable? Perhaps you can insert a short piece of a "smooth transition function" at the two points where the mirror images meet.

Comment: @JukkaKohonen Yes, smooth means infinitely differentiable. Oh, I haven't thought about such local perturbations. If there is such universal smooth transition it would do the job nicely. However, I was hoping for some cosine transform-like tricky gluing.

Comment: I have a hard time to imagine how such a procedure should look like for the simple function $f(x)=x$…

Comment: @Dirk Yeah, I stuck on identity as well... I have idea that such functions can be treat as smooth curves in projective plane... but I guess in such case we may loose information about function values.

Comment: Oh, it is not smooth in general.

Comment: You probably need to specify more precisely what properties you want $\Phi$ to have. There are of course injective maps, but that's just saying something about the cardinalities of the function spaces. (More explicitly, you could identify $[0,1]$ with just part of the circle, interpret the function as a function on that arc and extend smoothly.)

Comment: @ChristianRemling You are right, this answers my main answer somehow! Moreover, it shed some additional light on the problem.

Comment: You can just pick a smooth function $g$ which is non-zero on $(0, 1)$ but vanishes with all its derivatives at the endpoints. Then for the function $f$ take $fg$ and wrap it around the circle.